# Returning a payload value to Redux session is causing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, redux

I'm trying to implement a method to store in Redux session the counting of results from the base everytime the application also fetches it. The `componentWillReceiveProps` method is the following:

```
if (!countingTestAnnouncements && countingTestAnnouncementsSuccess) {
  let value = parseInt(totalTests.total);

  setCurrentValue(value);
}
```

It is clear. The method to store in the session will be executed when the counting is successful. This is the action file:

```
export const SET_CURRENT_VALUE = "hp:alert:set_current_value";

export function setCurrentValue(currentValue) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_CURRENT_VALUE,
      payload: currentValue
    })
  };
}

const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [SET_CURRENT_VALUE]: (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      currentValue: Value, action.payload
    }
  }
};

const initialState = {
  currentValue: null
};

export default function alertReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type];
  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
};
```

What is causing me a headache is the fact that when the `return` is reached within `ACTION_HANDLERS`, the looping will occur, and I do not know why it is happening.

```
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [SET_CURRENT_VALUE]: (state, action) => {
    // By commenting out the return block and putting
    // a console.log, the result will be seen only once,
    // as expected. But as it is, the loop will happen.
    return {
      ...state,
      currentValue: action.payload
    }

    // console.log(action.payload) will display once the counting.
  }
};
```

Why don't know why `componentWillReceiveProps` keeps repeating like this. What is really pissing me off is that the whole block is executed, the conditions of the `if` should be `false` and do not enter the block.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are calling "setCurrentValue(value)"  you are triggering and "componentWillReceiveProps" after the dispatch and this cause the loop.
It might be better to get this total in reducer  and pass it to store or to reset countingTestAnnouncementsSuccess in order to skip it on next update like given below:

```
if (!countingTestAnnouncements && countingTestAnnouncementsSuccess) {
    let value = parseInt(totalTests.total);
    countingTestAnnouncementsSuccess = false;
    setCurrentValue(value);
}
```

Comment: Resetting does not work because it is a variable from Redux, therefore it is read-only. When you say "store", what do you mean?

Comment: ok, you may set then countingTestAnnouncementsSuccess to false with the "SET_CURRENT_VALUE" reducer.  e.g.   return {
      ...state,
      currentValue: action.payload,    countingTestAnnouncementsSuccess: false
    }